# SQL Iterate over group by records

Tags: sql, jdbc, apache-drill

I have a table that looks like this

```
user_id | attr1 | attr2
--------+-------+-------
AAA     | 123   | 345
BBB     | 223   | 567
AAA     | 345   | 477
CCC     | 345   | 234
BBB     | 356   | 123
CCC     | 456   | 477
```

Clearly, the records can be grouped by `user_id`. What I want to do is batch/club records w.r.t `user_id` and then iterate over this group by retrieving all records under that user_id for further processing.

Something like after I group by `user_id` if want a list of lists. The inner list will contain separate record of the table and the outer list will contain list of al `user_id`.

So far I have come up with this -

`SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table;`  =====> put this in a list

iterate over the above list and execute below query

```
SELECT * FROM table where user_id = list[i]
```

I feel there must be a better way to do this. I am writing the boilerplate code in Java and this is a Drill query if that helps.

Comment: `distinct`is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra brackets and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table;` to make code clearer.

Comment: I will correct that @jarlh

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ordering the table by `user_id` and just retrieving the rows one at a time?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
ORDER BY user_id;
```

In the application, you can detect when the user_id changes for the processing.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion, I will clearly save query time. But then I build the logic in the app rather than in query. I was looking for a more SQL oriented solution? I dont know if thats correct way of thinking for this problem.

Comment: @Shan . . . You really want to return one result set and loop through that in the application -- rather than a separate query for each user.  You could enumerate the rows for each user, but checking if a counter is "1" hardly seems much simpler than checking if the `user_id` changes.